# Alter a field by select list in entity form

Tags: entities, ajax

I have a problem with Ajax and some fields in my entity form. i have a select list in my form and when i change the selected option i wanna increment another field. To explain better, i can create some entity called "modification", in this entity i have a select list with options "option 1, option 2, option3". When i will create an entity with "option 1", my field incrément will be "1", in a create a second entity with "option 1" the incrément will be "2". But if i create a third entity with "option 3" my increment will be "1".

The first thing i need to do is to collect the element list choosen automatically and do an EntityFieldQuery. When i got the count of result i just want to put the count in my field "increment".

Here is my code in hook_form_alter (field_pjt_phase is my list) :

```
$form['field_pjt_phase']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
     'event' => 'change',
     'callback' => 'projetcreate_modification_callback',
     //'wrapper' => 'field_event_1_role_replace',
);
```

And my callback :

```
function projetcreate_modification_callback($form, $form_state) {
      //$valeur = $form_state['values']['list_eltmission'];
      //My EntityQUery to take the last increment....
      //return $form['field_event_1_role'];
      var_dump($form);
}
```

And here a picture of my fields :

[image: My fields]

How can i execute the Query when i change the select list ? How to put the result of my coult entityquery in my second field ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your form alter add some code to check the form state like below to alter the text field value

  ```
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_pjt_phase'])) {
      $field_val = $form_state['values']['field_pjt_phase'];

      // write dynamic query to get the count of the particular field with $field_val  as a condition  
      $form['replace_textfield']['#value'] = $count;
    }
  ```
- Modify your Ajax callback by adding just `return $form['replace_textfield'];`

Comment: Ok thanks for the module ! I have two problems now. 

How can i pass my "$_REQUEST['project'] from my url to my ajax callback ? because when i choose a val in my list the value of $_REQUEST disappear.

Second question : Why the increment isn't added to my field ?

Comment: Ok i found how to pass the id. By the form_state.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the [aJax example module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/7), and specifically the [dependant example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7).

In that example, the seconds list is updated when the first list is changed, and it's value it updated according to its helper function `_ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($selected)` which is passed the value of the first list.

You could do something similar except use a simple text field for the second field but place the helper function on default value or value :

```
'#default_value' => _ajax_myentityfieldquery($selected),
```

and in the helper `_ajax_myentityfieldquery` return the result of your EntityFieldQuery function.